# Как пофиксить слайдер в попапе?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, slider, slick.js

Есть **слайдер (Slick slider)** **и он в попапе**. Попап реализован добавлениям класа который меняет `display:none` на `display: block`... *бла бла бла* ... по клику на кнопку (класика)... При загрузке страницы и когда **первый раз** откываешь попап слайдер ведет себя не адекватно, имеет неадекватную высоту и через секунду становится таким как нужно, как это пофиксить?[image]_______________________________________________________________________________

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Инициализировать слайдер после открытия попапа.
Например так: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgwRR-XHMMA